# Quotient and remainder for division a product of big integers by a big integer

Tags: c++, algorithm, overflow, biginteger

```
long long signed  A, B, C;
```

or

```
long long unsigned A, B, C;
```

I need to calculate quotient and remainder for expression `A * B / C`, where `A`,`B`,`C` are big integers, so that product `A * B` causes an overflow and `A < C` and `B < C`. Prohibited the use of floating point numbers and the use of third-party libraries. How it can be done?

Comment: This is not trivial. If you have access to x64 assembly, then you can use the `idiv` instruction... Otherwise, you're gonna need to use 128-bit integer arithmetic.

Comment: @Mysticial, yes, I want to know how to use 128-bit integer arithmetic for my question

Answer (score 3):

Remainder of `A*B/C` is equal to the product of remainders `A/C` and `B/C` modulo `C` again.

//EDIT: Ups, didn't see the conditions `A<C`, `B<C`. In that case try something like this:

```
tmp = A;
for (var i = 1; i<=B; i++)
{
   if (tmp + A == overflow || tmp + A >= C)
      tmp -= C;
   tmp += A;
}
```

The resulting `tmp` should be the remainder you seek. This will work as long as all of the inputs are positive and we are doing this in signed situation. Perhaps it will work for unsigned as well, didn't check it though.

Of course you need some fancy function to check the `oveflow` condition.

As for the quotient you can just evaluate `A/C` and then multiply it by `B`, can't you?

Answer (score 3):

Doing multiplication with arbitrary big integer is really pretty simple: you do exactly like you did when you were in scool and did it by hand on paper. But instead of working decimal numbers in base 10, you work with bytes or integers.

For example:

```
A = 12340;
B = 56789;
aa = new byte[] { A/256, A%256 };
bb = new byte[] { B/256, B%256 };
```

Now you can loop over the array and do the multiplication in smaller steps.

Comment: Thank you. I understand how to get product, but how after that I can perform divsion?

Comment: Exactly like on paper in base 10, but with base 256 for speed. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division

Answer (score 1):

I believe that a good start should be using c/c++ with [gmp](http://gmplib.org/). gmp is a arbitrary precision library that has all this operations implemented for arbitrary precision. It works with integers and float.

Edit: (no third party libs)

My second though about it (after gmp) was prime factorization. You need an algorithm for that. You create a vector with Afactorization, Bfactorization and Cfactorization which have the list of primes of the factorization. Then you test the primes of A/B against the ones in C, and start erasing them of the A/B and C vector. After all of them are tested, you multiply all the vector's members and do the normal division.

Comment: I'd like to, but I am not allowed to use of third-party libs.

Comment: Ups, sorry. Never the less, you can use its documentation has they have some algorithms explained.

Comment: @J.C.Leitão, It's possible that A, B, C - are coprimes

Answer (score 1):

For multiplying 32 bit numbers without 64 bit arithmetic, there is a method by [Schrage](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchragesAlgorithm.html). Maybe you can extend it to 64 bit multiplication.

Answer (score 1):

you have to split A and B into their upper and lower 32bit parts

```
A = Au * (1<<32) + Al
B = Bu * (1<<32) + Bl
```

(compute as `Au=A>>32; Al=A&(1<<(32)-1;`) and consider the products of these parts separately:

```
A*B = Au*Bu * (1<<64) + (Au*Bl+Al*Bu) * (1<<32) + Al*Bl
```

next you must divide each of these terms by C and accumulate the quotient and the remainder (be careful to avoid overflow!). In particular, Au*Bu>C is impossible due to your initial requirement.

Answer (score 1):

for example like this:

```
typedef long long ll;

const ll base = 1000*1000*1000; // 10^9 for example, could be also 1<<32 
               // or smth convenient, the goal is to store
               // the numbers and a result in 'base'-based numerical system
               // to avoid overflow

pair<ll, ll> p1 = make_pair( A/base, A%base ); // store the numbers in 
pair<ll, ll> p2 = make_pair( B/base, B%base ); // 'base'-based numerical system

vector<ll> v1(4);
v1[ 0 ] = p1.second * p2.second;
v1[ 1 ] = p1.first * p2.second + v1[ 0 ] / base; v1[ 0 ] %= base;
v1[ 2 ] = v1[ 1 ] / base; v1[ 1 ] %= base;

vector<ll> v2(4);
v2[ 1 ] = p1.second * p2.first;
v2[ 2 ] = p1.first * p2.first + v2[ 1 ] / base; v2[ 1 ] %= base;
v2[ 3 ] = v2[ 1 ] / base; v2[ 2 ] %= base;

ll tmp = 0;
for( i = 0; i < 4; ++i )
{
    v1[ i ] = v1[ i ] + v2[ i ] + tmp;
    tmp = v1[ i ] / base;
    v1[ i ] %= base;
}
```

now v1 stores the value of A*B represented in base 10^9. The rest is to carefully perform the division of it to C, which is rather an easy mathematical challenge :)

Comment: `p1.first*p2.first` may be greater than `base` so `high * base` may be greater than `1<<64`

Comment: +1. I have the same idea, but I was too lazy to implement this)